# file name parameter expansion bash

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, expansion

I am trying to find all files with a specific extension and change them to a different extension.  Both extensions will be put in as command line arguments.  How would I set a variable equal to the file name before the "." using parameter expansion? I am new to scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
name=${param%.*}
```

will set `name` to the value of `$param` without the extension.

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter%word}`
>   `${parameter%%word}`
>   The *word* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of *parameter*, then the result of the expansion is the value of *parameter* with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted.

Comment: Thank you! would you mind explaining what the % means?